# Analyzing presence/absence data for art history

Tags: r, binary-data

How can I best analyze the presence/absence data that I have gathered about the [illuminations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminated_manuscript) in a medieval manuscript? I have identified individual motifs in chapter headings and created a spreadsheet that has 1 or 0 for each (there are 37 motifs in total).

There were at least 4 people who worked on the manuscript, which is clear from simple motif that appears on all of the pages analyzed. I did PCA and color-coded the data points with this control variable, and it appears that the presence/absence of these other motifs does, to some extent, correlate with it. I was thinking that co-occurence analysis would be the next direction to explore, although I would be eager to learn of any other statistical techniques that might be useful for this type of data. Are there any pitfalls that I would need to be aware of, or any R packages that people would recommend?

Specifically, I want to figure out which motifs correlate with each of the 4 artists. If possible, I'd also like to be able to take into consideration the possibility that similarities could also result form shared models that the artists were looking at.

More specifically, I have run a correlation analysis using pearson's method on the pages created by a one of the four artists. How can I find closest correlations from the resulting dataframe, and how can I determine if they are statistically significant?